# create multipart form data with the same field names and different file types

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have a problem with creating multipart-form data. I need to have the data with 3 files (each of file should have exactly the same field name) and json value. I am using MultipartEncoder to do this, but to create data it uses dictionary - thats why I cannot set three exactly the same field values. How can I do it?

Here is a piece of my code, that works but the files called "mffc" has different field names, and should be called only "mfcc"

piece of my code:

```
data = MultipartEncoder(
fields={
    'prototypeModel': ('prototypeModel', open(prototypeModel, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream'),
    'mfcc_1': ('mfcc_1', open(mfcc_1, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream'),
    'mfcc_2': ('mfcc_2', open(mfcc_2, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream'),
    'mfcc_3': ('mfcc_3', open(mfcc_3, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream'),
    'declaredParameters': json.dumps(declaredParameters)
}
)

print( '---------------------- start enroll ----------------------')
testEnrollResponse = requests.post(server+sessionID, data=data, headers={'Content-Type': data.content_type})
multipart_data = decoder.MultipartDecoder.from_response(testEnrollResponse)
userModel_out = multipart_data.parts[0].content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list of tuples, e.g.,

```
data = MultipartEncoder(
    fields=[
        ('prototypeModel': (...)),
        ('mfcc', ('mfcc', ...)),
        ('mfcc', ('mfcc', ...)),
        ('mfcc', ('mfcc', ...)),
        (declaredParameters', ...),
    ]
 )
```